# How to loop through the columns in a table using SQL SELECT in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table 'ABC' that has columns 'prod1_name', 'prod1_percentage',
'prod2_name', 'prod2_percentage' and so on until 'prod15_name', 'prod15_percentage'. Each column (from 1-15) may or may not have value.

Question - how can I use a loop to get the non-null values from the columns instead of listing each column names in the SQL SELECT?

[image: This picture illustrates what I meant]

Comment: What about using "SELECT * FROM 'ABC'"?

Comment: just added a picture link in my question to illustrate what I meant

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand the question, but here's a few options:

You can get a list of schemas, tables, and columns for any table by querying the system views.

```
SELECT s.name, o.name, c.name
FROM sys.schemas s
    INNER JOIN sys.objects o
        ON o.schema_id = s.schema_id
    INNER JOIN sys.columns c
        ON c.object_id = o.object_id
WHERE s.name = @schemaName
    AND o.name = @tableName
```

You can throw this into a cursor if you need to do something dynamic with them by prefixing the above with something similar to:

```
DECLARE schemaRunner CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
```

From there, measure @@FETCH_STATUS in a while loop to grab your variables and do something to them:

```
--cursor definition
OPEN schemaRunner
FETCH NEXT FROM shcemaRunner into @sName, @tName, @cName
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    --...DO SOMETHING TO THE VARIABLES HERE
    FETCH NEXT FROM shcemaRunner into @sName, @tName, @cName
END
CLOSE schemaRunner
DEALLOCATE schemarunner
```

Now, for your question - Not selecting columns if they're null - so if all rows have them null? So, you could measure that in the DO SOMETHING portion of the above, and add or flag the columns if they come back true, so...

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'' -- THIS LINE SHOULD BE OUTSIDE, BEFORE THE LOOP.

SET @SQL = 'IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM ABC WHERE ' + @cName + ' IS NOT NULL) INSERT INTO <someTrackingTable> VALUES (''' + @cName + ''')'
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL
```

Then, after the loop runs, you can construct your column list for your statement:

```
SELECT STUFF((
    SELECT ', ' + Name
    FROM <someTrackingTable>
    FOR XML PATH('')
    ), 1, 2,'') AS Columns
```

This is a bit involved, but you are asking for a complex item.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have just added a picture in my question to illustrate what I meant. Is there any simple statement I can embed in a sql select to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0):

This is an unpivot operation.  I would use `cross apply`:

```
select t.productid, v.mixcomponent, v.mixpercentage
from t cross apply
     (values (mix1component, mix1percentage),
             (mix2component, mix2percentage),
             (mix3component, mix3percentage),
             (mix4component, mix4percentage),
             . . . 
     ) v(mixcomponent, mixpercentage)
where mixcomponent is not null;
```